# Possible parameter/combinations for GetAsyncKeyState - C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to find out the total list of parameters for function **GetAsyncKeyState()**

I have checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and many other Google search results pages but cannot find a definite answer.

For example

```
char t = 58; (Would be number 4)
char y = 8;  (Would be BACKSPACE key)
```

My reason to know these is so that I can use a loop to query the function with each possible parameter.

```
for(i = 0; i <= 500; i++) 
{
      if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
      {
           cout << "key pressed : ";
           cout << i << endl;
      }

 }
```

I would rather know the possible parameters and not take a shot in the dark randomly as in my loop checking upto 500.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks, I did find that page, but I don't understand fully how it maps out, for example if we test *char t = 45*, we get character *-*. On that list you send, *0x45* is character E. I do see the difference that 45 != 0x45, but do you know how I can correctly test for this? Also the list does not specify the lower case alpha characters.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? The `&& 1` in the if statement doesn't do anything. If you want to test against a certain value, c++ accepts hex literals, just write `0x45` in the code.

Comment: You should be testing the MSB: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000)`. There's also `GetKeyboardState`.

Comment: @TartanLlama I am new to C++, and presuming that to catch which key has been pressed, I must run all through the function testing if that key == -32767. *ex if (GetAsyncKeyState(45) == -32767)* we know that key - has been/is pressed.

Comment: It tests a *virtual key*, doesn't have anything to do with a character.  What character you get when you press a key depends on the keyboard layout.  A Russian keyboard looks *very* different from an English one.  There are 256 possible virtual keys.  Testing if the virtual key is down should be done by testing for `< 0` or `& 0x8000`.

Comment: @HansPassant So with that said, Should my loop test for virtual key 0 - 256?
Using the virtual keys chart linked above, I would have to write alot of loops/if statements according to the change in values if I test by them, Example - 0x4B (K Key), 0x54 (T Key), 0xA1 (Right Shift), 0xFE (Clear Key)

Comment: That adds up to 257 keys, programmers stop counting at 255.  Using GetAsyncKeyState() is wrong about 98.42% of the time.  You are typically only interested when a key goes down, maybe up but that's a stretch.  If you create a console mode app, the usual home for a C++ program, then you tend to use _getch(), ReadConsoleInput() if you don't mind making OS calls.

Comment: Yes its a console app, however I want to monitor all keyboard activity, not just through my app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of all the keys here: [VirtualKeycodes github repo](https://github.com/Indieteur/VirtualKeycodes/blob/b169f56fbb22342ac89421ab8204e3ad480e20b7/VirtualKeycodes.cs)

I have made a proof of concept logger using these keys, I converted them to to an std::map format and put them in an std::array.

I loop through them and log all keys that are pressed, it includes 336 virtual keys which should be ALL of them.

Output looks like:

[image]

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

std::array<std::pair<char*, BYTE>, 336> vkeys
{ {
    { "Backspace", 0x08 },
    { "Tab" , 0x09 },
    { "Clear" , 0x0C },
    { "Enter" , 0x0D },
    { "Shift" , 0x10 },
    { "Control" , 0x11 },
    { "Alt" , 0x12 },
    { "Pause" , 0x13 },
    { "Capslock" , 0x14 },
    { "Kana" , 0x15 },
    { "Hanguel" , 0x15 },
    { "Hangul" , 0x15 },
    { "Junja" , 0x17 },
    { "Final" , 0x18 },
    { "Hanja" , 0x19 },
    { "Kanji" , 0x19 },
    { "Esc" , 0x1B },
    { "Convert" , 0x1C },
    { "NonConvert" , 0x1D },
    { "Accept" , 0x1E },
    { "ModeChange" , 0x1F },
    { "Space" , 0x20 },
    { "PageUp" , 0x21 },
    { "PageDown" , 0x22 },
    { "End" , 0x23 },
    { "Home" , 0x24 },
    { "LeftArrow" , 0x25 },
    { "UpArrow" , 0x26 },
    { "RightArrow" , 0x27 },
    { "DownArrow" , 0x28 },
    { "Select" , 0x29 },
    { "Print" , 0x2A },
    { "Execute" , 0x2B },
    { "PrintScreen" , 0x2C },
    { "Insert" , 0x2D },
    { "Delete" , 0x2E },
    { "Help" , 0x2F },
    { "Alphanumeric_0" , 0x30 },
    { "Alphanumeric_1" , 0x31 },
    { "Alphanumeric_2" , 0x32 },
    { "Alphanumeric_3" , 0x33 },
    { "Alphanumeric_4" , 0x34 },
    { "Alphanumeric_5" , 0x35 },
    { "Alphanumeric_6" , 0x36 },
    { "Alphanumeric_7" , 0x37 },
    { "Alphanumeric_8" , 0x38 },
    { "Alphanumeric_9" , 0x39 },
    { "A" , 0x41 },
    { "B" , 0x42 },
    { "C" , 0x43 },
    { "D" , 0x44 },
    { "E" , 0x45 },
    { "F" , 0x46 },
    { "G" , 0x47 },
    { "H" , 0x48 },
    { "I" , 0x49 },
    { "J" , 0x4A },
    { "K" , 0x4B },
    { "L" , 0x4C },
    { "M" , 0x4D },
    { "N" , 0x4E },
    { "O" , 0x4F },
    { "P" , 0x50 },
    { "Q" , 0x51 },
    { "R" , 0x52 },
    { "S" , 0x53 },
    { "T" , 0x54 },
    { "U" , 0x55 },
    { "V" , 0x56 },
    { "W" , 0x57 },
    { "X" , 0x58 },
    { "Y" , 0x59 },
    { "Z" , 0x5A },
    { "LeftWin" , 0x5B },
    { "RightWin" , 0x5C },
    { "Apps" , 0x5D },
    { "Sleep" , 0x5F },
    { "Numpad_0" , 0x60 },
    { "Numpad_1" , 0x61 },
    { "Numpad_2" , 0x62 },
    { "Numpad_3" , 0x63 },
    { "Numpad_4" , 0x64 },
    { "Numpad_5" , 0x65 },
    { "Numpad_6" , 0x66 },
    { "Numpad_7" , 0x67 },
    { "Numpad_8" , 0x68 },
    { "Numpad_9" , 0x69 },
    { "Multiply" , 0x6A },
    { "Add" , 0x6B },
    { "Separator" , 0x6C },
    { "Subtract" , 0x6D },
    { "Decimal" , 0x6E },
    { "Divide" , 0x6F },
    { "F1" , 0x70 },
    { "F2" , 0x71 },
    { "F3" , 0x72 },
    { "F4" , 0x73 },
    { "F5" , 0x74 },
    { "F6" , 0x75 },
    { "F7" , 0x76 },
    { "F8" , 0x77 },
    { "F9" , 0x78 },
    { "F10" , 0x79 },
    { "F11" , 0x7A },
    { "F12" , 0x7B },
    { "F13" , 0x7C },
    { "F14" , 0x7D },
    { "F15" , 0x7E },
    { "F16" , 0x7F },
    { "F17" , 0x80 },
    { "F18" , 0x81 },
    { "F19" , 0x82 },
    { "F20" , 0x83 },
    { "F21" , 0x84 },
    { "F22" , 0x85 },
    { "F23" , 0x86 },
    { "F24" , 0x87 },
    { "Numlock" , 0x90 },
    { "ScrollLock" , 0x91 },
    { "LeftShift" , 0xA0 },
    { "RightShift" , 0xA1 },
    { "LeftCtrl" , 0xA2 },
    { "RightCtrl" , 0xA3 },
    { "LeftAlt" , 0xA4 },
    { "RightAlt" , 0xA5 },
    { "BrowserBack" , 0xA6 },
    { "BrowserForward" , 0xA7 },
    { "BrowserRefresh" , 0xA8 },
    { "BrowserStop" , 0xA9 },
    { "BrowserSearch" , 0xAA },
    { "BrowserFavorites" , 0xAB },
    { "BrowserHome" , 0xAC },
    { "VolumeMute" , 0xAD },
    { "VolumeDown" , 0xAE },
    { "VolumeUp" , 0xAF },
    { "MediaNextTrack" , 0xB0 },
    { "MediaPrevTrack" , 0xB1 },
    { "MediaStop" , 0xB2 },
    { "MediaPlayPause" , 0xB3 },
    { "LaunchMail" , 0xB4 },
    { "LaunchMedia" , 0xB5 },
    { "LaunchApp1" , 0xB6 },
    { "LaunchApp2" , 0xB7 },
    { "OEM_1" , 0xBA },
    { "OEM_Plus" , 0xBB },
    { "OEM_Comma" , 0xBC },
    { "OEM_Minus" , 0xBD },
    { "OEM_Period" , 0xBE },
    { "OEM_2" , 0xBF },
    { "OEM_3" , 0xC0 },
    { "OEM_4" , 0xDB },
    { "OEM_5" , 0xDC },
    { "OEM_6" , 0xDD },
    { "OEM_7" , 0xDE },
    { "OEM_8" , 0xDF },
    { "OEM_102" , 0xE2 },
    { "ProcessKey" , 0xE5 },
    { "Packet" , 0xE7 },
    { "Attn" , 0xF6 },
    { "CrSel" , 0xF7 },
    { "ExSel" , 0xF8 },
    { "EREOF" , 0xF9 },
    { "Play" , 0xFA },
    { "Zoom" , 0xFB },
    { "NONAME" , 0xFC },
    { "PA1" , 0xFD },
    { "OEM_Clear" , 0xFE },
    { "None" , 0x00 }
} };

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (auto vk : vkeys)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(vk.second) & 1)
            {
                std::cout << vk.first << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```